# exec format error when running AWS Golang Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-go

I have a go application, structured like this:

cmd
|
reports
|
main.go

main.go imports `internal/reports` package and has a single function, main(), which delegates call to `aws-lambda-go/lambda.Start()` function.

Code is build running the commands (snippet):

```
cd internal/reports && go build handler.go
cd ../..
go build -o reports ../cmd/reports/main.go && chmod +x reports && zip reports.zip reports
```

`reports.zip` is uploaded to AWS Lambda, which in turns throws an error when `Test` button is pressed:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/reports: exec format error",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

`reports` is set as Lambda's `Handler`.

Also, code is build on Ubuntu 14.04 machine, as a part of `aws/codebuild/ubuntu-base:14.04` Docker Image, on **AWS CodeBuild**. There should be no environment issues here, even though the error suggests a cross-platform problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue is that main() function is not declared in `main` package, which is mandatory by Golang [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

Comment: Thanks, this would have been really tough to catch given the error message.

Comment: I completely missed your comment and wasted hours on this! Thank you for sharing. It was exactly this!

Comment: I have the same issue and i also declare main() function

Answer (score 87):

You have to build with `GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux`.
Wherever you build your binary, the binary for Lambda is run on Amazon Linux.

So , try this build command.

`GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build handler.go`

Comment: hmm build in Windows 10 only works for me when "GOOS=", and then I have to set "GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux" to get build-lambda-zip.exe to work

Comment: running "go get -u golang.org/x/crypto/md4" fixed the issue for me, not sure why I had to do that

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html#golang-package-windows gave the details I needed on Windows, but this answer pointed me there

Comment: A lot of the Amazon documentation and online walkthroughs skip/ignore the `GOARCH=amd64` piece. If you're on one of the new Mac M1 chips this is required.