# "PathError" when deploying Go project to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

When deploying this [Go-based AWS Lambda project](https://github.com/chuckha/marriage), via AWS console, I receive:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/main: exec format error",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

Here are the steps I took:

- downloaded the `marriage-master` project from Git
- in Terminal, `go get "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"` [so the script is buildable by Go](https://medium.com/@daniel.woods/deploying-a-golang-package-to-aws-lambda-in-5-minutes-cd11685f576)
- in Terminal, `go build main.go` to create file Lambda will use to execute
- in Terminal, `zip main.zip main` to archive the file into a [.zip for deployment to Lambda](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfcyvzyoc4oln9q/marriage-master.zip?dl=0)
- in AWS Console, upload `main.zip` to `Function code`

[image]

- in AWS Console, changed `Handler` to `main`.

[image]

But I keep getting this path error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you running on? If you're running on Windows or macOS, did you make sure to build a Linux binary?

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.15.6 (19G60d), and no I don't think I did. Do you have instructions you can share?

Comment: No but Amazon does: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To deploy a Go app in AWS Lambda, run the following commands:

1. Build the binary targeted to Linux OS and amd64 architecture

   GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build main.go -ldflags="-s -w"
2. Zip the binary

   zip lambda.zip main
3. Upload this binary from AWS Lambda console directly or Put it in an S3 bucket and import it.

You have taken care of the lambda configuration already.

Comment: I get `can't load package: named files must be .go files: -ldflags=-s -w`

Comment: try removing main.go? GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w"

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but then when I zip the binary, I get `zip warning: name not matched: main zip error: Nothing to do! (main.zip)`

Comment: Check your binary name @MSD.

Answer (score 7):

Try without flags:

```
GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build main.go
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this `GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build main.go` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was the package name wasn't named `main`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50701572/2639163